# AngularJS post promise

Tags: angularjs

What is acually resolve and postpromise for?

the posts postpromise is to get posts and display them later on.
and i want to do the same with sideactions, but how can i make this work?

I have the following code:

```
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url : '/home',
    templateUrl : '/home.html',
    controller : 'MainCtrl',
    resolve : {
            postPromise : ['posts',
        function(posts) {
            return posts.getAll();
        }]
})
```

but i want to add an additional postpromise.

i tried:

```
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
    url : '/home',
    templateUrl : '/home.html',
    controller : 'MainCtrl',
    resolve : {

    postPromise : ['posts',
        function(posts) {
            return posts.getAll();
        }],
    postPromise: ['sideactions',
        function(posts) {
            return actions.latestActions();
        }]

    }
})
```

but that wont work.

How can i make multiple postpromises to the resolve?

Comment: Did it work for you, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `resolve` you can pass data to your controller. Property named `postPromise` can be replaced with anything you want but there can't be two properties with same name.

Also, in your second `postPromise` your service names does not match.

Here's an example how to resolve data, using mock services.

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <a ui-sref="home">click here for state:home</a>
  <div ui-view></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
  .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        template: '<div>home template {{ data | json }}</div>',
        controller: function($scope, posts, actions) {
          $scope.data = posts.concat(actions);
        },
        resolve: {
          posts: ['postService', function(postService) {
            return postService.getAll();
          }],
          actions: ['actionService', function(actionService) {
            return actionService.getActions();
          }]
        }
      });
  }])
  .factory('postService', ['$q', function($q) {
    return {
      getAll: function() {
        return $q.when(['post1','post2']);
      }
    };
  }])
  .factory('actionService', ['$q', function($q) {
    return {
      getActions: function() {
        return $q.when(['action1','action2']);
      }
    };
  }]);
```

---

[image]

Related plunker can be found here https://plnkr.co/edit/uOBPQu

Comment: Ah, forgot you cant use $q in config phase... updated my answer.

Comment: can we chat @mikko viitala ?